# What methods other than NHProf allow you to view the dynamic SQL generated by nhibernate?

Tags: nhibernate

Before NHibernate Profiler was released I was parsing through logs generated by log4net.  Today I use NHibernate Profiler, but what other tools / techniques exist that allow a developer to view the dynamic SQL generated by nhibernate?

Comment: What were your concerns regarding the log4net option?  log4net is pretty flexible and does more than just log files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this link: http://szahariev.blogspot.com/2010/01/nhibernate-display-executed-sql-at.html

I've never tried it because we bought NHProf, but I think it has potential when paired with a IsDevelopment flag in a config file.

Answer (score 3):

Sql profiler, but NHibernate profiler is best tool to do it.